# Using latent variable as independent variable in regression

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model, latent-variable, weighted-regression, latent-class

I ran latent class analysis using `poLCA` package and each observation in my dataset has been assigned a class based on the highest posterior probability (modal assignment). I would like to use these assigned class a independent categorical variable in my log-linked Gamma generalised linear model (GLM). I understand that I should correct for bias from misclassification of the latent class if I want to use it as independent variable. [Bakk (2013)](http://journals.sagepub.com/doi/abs/10.1177/0081175012470644) proposed a method of correcting bias using D matrix. But all analysis was done in Latent Gold. Is there an alternative way to correct for bias in R? Is one of the ways by using the probability weights function in glm function?

```
> library(poLCA)
> data(house_votes84)
> house_votes84=house_votes84+1
> house_votes84=as.data.frame(house_votes84)
> names(house_vote84)=c('n1','n2','n3','n4',n5','n6','n7',
  'n8','n9','n10','n11','n12','n13','n14','n15','n16')
> set.seed(123)
> house_votes84$y=ceiling(rgamma(435,shape=1,scale=1:10))
> house_votes84$x1=rbinom(435,1,0.5)
> f<-cbind(n1,n2,n3,n4,n5,n6,n7,n8,n9,n10,n11)~1
> lca3<-poLCA(f,house_vote84,nclass=3,nrep=5)
> house_votes84$latentclass=a1$predclass
> model1=glm(y~as.factor(x1)*as.factor(latentclass), data=house_data84,family=Gamma(link="log"))
```

Comment: I don't know the specific answer to your question but there might be something helpful in the many academic papers on the *Latent Gold* website (www.statisticalinnovations.com).

Comment: Good idea to tag this with R, because the whole world doesn't yet use it or even recognise it. At the same time, appears off-topic as you're asking for how to do something in R.

Comment: Your best bet might be to use a dedicated structural modeling package like `lavaan` or `openMx`, or alternatively, a Bayesian MCMC approach via `Stan` or `JAGS`. All of these are free (as in speech and beer) and can be used within `R`.